# SKPolyline options not working on Android

Tags: android, skmaps

I am adding an `SKPolyline` to my map and trying to set the width of the line. The [documentation](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.5.1/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKPolyline.html) is incomplete and nothing but setting the color and identifier of the line works.

Here's a method:

```
private void addPolylineToMap(SKPolyline polyline) {
    polyline.setIdentifier(0);
    polyline.setLineSize(9);
    polyline.setOutlineSize(4);
    polyline.setOutlineColor(new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1});
    polyline.setOutlineDottedPixelsSolid(6);
    polyline.setOutlineDottedPixelsSkip(0);
    mapView.addPolyline(polyline);
}
```

The result is a polyline with the color and nodes I specified outside of the method, but nothing else changed.

I am using the latest Android Skobbler SDK (2.5.1), does anyone have any idea how to make this work?

Comment: sorry, but there is no Android 2.5... du you mean you're using sdk _tools_ 25.1? that still doesn't tell us which SDK you're using

Comment: @Lovis "com.skobbler.ngx:SKMaps:2.5.1" edited for clarity

Comment: The documentation you are pointing to is from the 2.1.0 documentation - you should point either to the 2.5.1 (http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.5.1/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKPolyline.html or http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKPolyline.html)

Comment: @Ando I changed it to the SDK I am using. Still incomplete docs, doesn't mention the 10 width limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there are some issues with the option. I think the biggest limitation is that the "width" of the polyline is limited to 10 - this includes both the line and it's outline (the width issue will be handled in a future release). Since the SDK will only display 10 it will "cut" the outline out of the picture.

Using "thinner" settings does show the outline:

```
 SKPolyline polyline = new SKPolyline();
    // set the nodes on the polyline
    nodes = new ArrayList<SKCoordinate>();
    nodes.add(new SKCoordinate(-122.4342, 37.7898));
    nodes.add(new SKCoordinate(-122.4141, 37.7898));
    nodes.add(new SKCoordinate(-122.4342, 37.7753));
    polyline.setNodes(nodes);
    // set polyline color
    polyline.setColor(new float[]{0f, 0f, 1f, 1f});
    // set properties for the outline
    polyline.setLineSize(3);
    polyline.setOutlineSize(6);
    polyline.setOutlineColor(new float[]{1f, 0f, 0f, 1f});
    polyline.setOutlineDottedPixelsSolid(3);
    polyline.setOutlineDottedPixelsSkip(0);
    polyline.setIdentifier(12);
    mapView.addPolyline(polyline);
```

[image]